# Can I create a number with decimal point in number field?

Tags: number

Could number for example `7.5` be created in number field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/number-fields), there is a setting where you can specify how many decimal places are allowed. So yes, 7.5 can be represented in a number field.